# RhinoMocks - Testing property values on reference types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I need to test logic that executes a function, after which it changes a property on the parameter and then executes the same function with the updated parameter.

To help illustrate this, here is some sample code:

Interface:
   `public interface IWorker`
 {
   `MyObjectB DoWork(MyObject myObject);`
 }

MyObjectB:
   `public class MyObjectB`
 {
   `public string Message { get; set; }`
 }

Implementation:

```
public MyObjectB DoWork(IWorker worker, MyObject myObject)
{
    worker.DoWork(myObject);
    myObject.Name = "PersonB";
    worker.DoWork(myObject);
    return new MyObjectB() { Message = "Done" };
}
```

Test:

```
    public void RhinoMocksSampleTest()
    {
     var workerStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IWorker>();
     workerStub.Stub(n => n.DoWork(Arg<MyObject>.Is.Anything));

     var myObj = new MyObject { Id = 1, Name = "PersonA" };

     var p = new Program();
     p.DoWork(workerStub, myObj);

     workerStub.AssertWasCalled(d => d.DoWork(Arg<MyObject>.Matches(r => r.Name == "PersonA")));

     workerStub.AssertWasCalled(d => d.DoWork(Arg<MyObject>.Matches(r => r.Name == "PersonB")));
    }
```

The first AssertWasCalled fails because the value is ‘PersonB’. 
Is there a function/call I can use to test the state of the object for the first call?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do what you're trying to do:

```
public void RhinoMocksSampleTest()
{
    var workerMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IWorker>();
    workerMock.Expect(d => d.DoWork(Arg<MyObject>.Matches(r => r.Name == "PersonA")));
    workerMock.Expect(d => d.DoWork(Arg<MyObject>.Matches(r => r.Name == "PersonB")));

    var myObj = new MyObject { Id = 1, Name = "PersonA" };
    var p = new Program();
    p.DoWork(workerMock , myObj);

    workerMock.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Comment: Hi @aprescott,

Thanks for the answer, but I need to be able to check that the first call is made with certain values and the second call with the updated values.

Comment: This would actually do that. Since we're using Expect instead of Stub, the final call to VerifyAllExpectations will fail if both calls aren't made. Try it out--it'll fail if the first call isn't made.

Comment: I might have not made it clear what I meant. I need to be able to check that the first call was made with 'PersonA' and the second call with 'PersonB', and not the other way around.

Comment: So you just need it to be ordered? See if this helps: http://japikse.blogspot.com/2009/03/verifying-order-of-method-execution.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to nice answer what aprescott has provided I can show another one approach which could be useful in some situations:

The idea is to manually store values which you are interesting in into some collection. Then you will be able to assert that collection contains required sequense.

```
    public void MyTest()
    {
        // that is list which will contain passed names
        var actualNames = new List<string>();

        // stub only saves passed Name property into list
        var workerStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IWorker>();
        workerStub
            .Stub(w => w.DoWork(Arg<MyObject>.Is.Anything))
            .Do((Action<MyObject>)(mo => actualNames.Add(mo.Name)));

        var myObject = new MyObject { Name = "PersonA" };
        var target = new MyWorker();

        target.DoWork(workerStub, myObject);

        // here we do assert that names list contains what is required
        Assert.That(actualNames, Is.EqualTo(new[] { "PersonA", "PersonB" }));
    }
```

PS. Yeah, it works for case when you need check that calls order is correct :)

Comment: Thanks @Alexander,

I think your approach might just do the trick; there is just one problem with it. Please see the updated sample code. Do you know how I can achieve the same when the resulting object is different?

Comment: Example which I've shown doesn't consider return value at all. It verifies parameters passed to `worker` only. If you need to assert returned value just write another test :)

Comment: I don't really care about the return value in this test, I still need to validate only the argument passed to the function.

Comment: What issue with parameter assertion are you getting? btw in your question editions I can see no changes with parameters. Have you missed something?